# Oracle SQL | How would I change a text field to a date field with a specific format?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Say I have the following rows

```
DATE
2016-04
2015-11
2009-08
```

And I want them to appear like this, with the date always set to the first of the month

```
DATE
01-APR-2016
01-NOV-2015
01-AUG-2009
```

Comment: So .. those "dates" are stored as varchars, aren't they ?  I'll refrain from preaching about how bad an idea that is ... O.o ... oops.

Comment: @Ditto: I'm the first one to preach that too. But to be fair: those aren't "real" dates. You can't store something like "April, 2016" in a date column because you always need a day as well. And then you wouldn't be able to distinguis "April, 2016" from "April 1st, 2016"

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not control how the table data types are handled. I'm trying to make use of what I can to compensate for them.

Comment: sure you can .. you just "fix the day" to a 1 ... and keep going ... you just "ignore" the day portion .. *shrug* ... I understand it's a grey(er) area .. but still .. ;) he obviously wants the 1 .. since he's trying to show it ... so it should've been put in in the first place ;)

Comment: Tom Kyte talks about this here:  https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:77598210939534   and  https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4473764100346558642  In short, anything "date-like" store as a date ... using string or number opens up all sorts of problems ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first convert your "month date" into a real date using `to_date()`:

```
to_date(the_column||'-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Note that you need to add a day (`||'-01'`) in order to have a valid input for the `to_date()` function.

and then you can format the resulting date as you like using `to_char()`

```
select to_char(to_date(the_column||'-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'dd-mon-yyyy')
from the_table;
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure adding "-01" is not mandatory. `to_date(the_column,'yyyy-mm')` works just fine for me .

Comment: @a1ex07: interesting. I wasn't aware of that - is this documented somewhere? I did a quick look at the manual but couldn't find anything stating how "missing" fields are initialized.

Comment: I don't have a link , but I'm certain it should be mentioned somewhere. Missing fields seem to be initialized with minimum possible value. For instance, if you add time format , e.g. `to_char(to_date(the_column,...), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')` it's gonna return value with time set to zeros. or 12 if you put just `hh`.

Answer (score 2):

to answer your immediate question:

```
  drop table junk;

  create table junk ( notadate  varchar2(7) );

  insert into junk values ( '2016-04' );
  insert into junk values ( '2015-11' );
  insert into junk values ( '2009-08' );

  commit;

  alter session set nls_date_format='dd-mon-yyyy';

  select to_date(notadate,'yyyy-mm') from junk;

  TO_DATE(NOT
  -----------
  01-apr-2016
  01-nov-2015
  01-aug-2009
```

However, I'd probably recommend doing the following:

```
  alter table junk add ( mydate  date );

  update junk
     set mydate = to_date(notadate,'yyyy-mm')
  /

  alter table junk drop ( notadate );
```

and use that new, DATE column .. properly ...

```
  select * from junk;

  MYDATE
  -----------
  01-apr-2016
  01-nov-2015
  01-aug-2009


  select to_char(mydate, 'yyyy-mm') from junk;
  (if needed)

  TO_CHAR
  -------
  2016-04
  2015-11
  2009-08
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all append date in addition to month and year to the text.

Then use to_date()

and then for date formatting use:
`ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format='dd-mm-yyyy'`;

Answer (score 1):

Use the `to_char` Function

```
SELECT to_char("DATE", 'DD-FMMon-YYYY') AS "DATE"
FROM yourtable;
```

Output

```
DATE
01-Apr-2016
01-Nov-2015
01-Aug-2009
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8ea1df/16/0